# PHP to return video file without public access

Tags: php

Long story short is that I want to show a video on my site to people who are logged in. Without logging in you shouldn't be able to see them or access them publicly for that matter.

That mean I put the video files into a folder without public access, only accessible by www-data.

Now to make it a little simpler, I'll use basic html and php files. Let's say I'm using uikit video player.

video.html

```
<div id="video-box" class="video-card__box" style="display: none">
     <video id="video" class="uk-responsive-width" width="auto" height="auto">
         <source src="fileHandler.php?file=video.mp4"></source>
     </video>
</div>
```

Now what should be in the PHP file? This for example just downloads the file whereas I want to display it in the videoplayer:

fileHandler.php

```
if (Auth::check())
{
      header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
      header('Content-Length: ' . $size); // Lets say I know the filesize
      fpassthru(fopen($_GET['file']), 'rb'));
}
```

I hope you understand the situation I'm in. I've been thinking about it for days and just tonight tried to solve the issue.

Comment: Surely it won't try to download it when used as a source for the HTML5 video tag?

Comment: I think your approach is correct, just make sure that the mp4 file is not publicly  accessible

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about passing the video file through PHP, which is not a good idea because:

- You will get 1 PHP process continuously running for each video stream, which consumes memory and resources and extends you max_execution_time. It's very easy to run out of processes this way, if you have even moderate load on your website.
- You're gonna have a hard time implementing HTTP features that a normal HTTP server will give you for free. Like streaming from the middle of the file.

A proper solution: use [nginx' auth_request module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) so your PHP code will only handle the authorization, and then nginx will do the video streaming (which it's very good at).